# Why is bias not defined for non-stationary MDP policies?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The Handbook of Markov Decision Processes [1](http://webee.technion.ac.il/~adam/MDPHandBook/index.html) defines bias of a stationary deterministic policy as follows:

$h(x, \phi) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} E[r(x_n, \phi(x_n)) - w(x_n , \phi)]$

where $x$ is a state, $\phi$ is a stationary deterministic policy, $r(s, a)$ is the mean reward of taking action $a$ in state $x$ and $w(x, \phi)$ is the expected reward per unit time while following policy $\phi$.

Later the same book also mentions that bias is undefined for non-stationary policies. What is it about non-stationary policies that precludes a bias definition?

Comment: Good question. Have you tried defining the bias of a non-stationary policy? If successful, can you show your definition? If not, what is the obstruction?

Comment: Thanks @Apass.Jack for your comment. I think the obstruction could be that the expectation on the RHS is supposed to be wrt a specific action $\phi(x)$ for a state $x$ (independent of the current $t$) and for a non-stationary policy that is not the case. Is that correct?